# Extract results from different ResultSets order by data

Tags: java, sql, json, sqlite

i have 4 ResultSet obtained by for 4 differents queries. 
I would to create a JSON object with the attribues of these differents ResultSets merged ordered by a parameter of each record having a Datetime type.

Suppose this case:

```
ResultSet rs1 = from query ("select a, date from table order by date");
ResultSet rs2 = from query ("select b, c, date from table1 order by date");
ResultSet rs3 = from query ("select d, e, f, date from table2 order by date");
ResultSet rs4 = from query ("select g, h, i, l, date from table3 order by date");
```

As you can see above, the ResultSets have differents extracted fields, different number of extracted fields etc..the only common info is the field "data" that is present in all the ResultSed as LAST FIELD (LAST INDEX OF THE QUERIES).

Then I would to obtain a JSON like this: 
note that the object with minor index is the most recent, the object with last index is the oldest considering "data" field

```
{"numberObjects":5,
a1:"valuea1",
data1:"valueDataa1",
d2:"valued2",
e2:"valuee2",
f2:"valuef2",
...}
```

There is a way to do this thing? The only procedure that i know is very very laboriuous so i ask you if oyu know a way faster and easier to actuate this thing..thanks to all.

Comment: That’s not entirely clear to me. Maybe you want to give a small example of data in the result sets and desired data in the JSON? If the spec is clear, I’m sure it can be done.

Comment: Did you try anyting yourself? Do any research?

Comment: If I understand correctly that you want only the oldest and/or the newest row from each result set, could we modify the SQL to return only the desired row?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a compound query to sort everything at once; this requires that the component queries return the same number of columns:

```sql
SELECT a, NULL, NULL, NULL, date FROM tab1
UNION ALL
SELECT b, c, d, e, date FROM tab2
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
ORDER BY date;
```